# Docker compose web stack

Tags: symfony, composer-php, docker-compose

I try to build a web stack with docker using "php, mariadb, ngnix, composer"
I try to use only container from official repositories

following my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx
      container_name: nginx
      ports:
        - "8000:80"
    mariadb:
      image: mariadb
      container_name: mariadb
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER : root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    php:
      image: php:fpm
      container_name: php
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      volumes:
        - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    composer:
      image: composer
      container_name: composer
      volumes_from:
        - php
      working_dir: /var/www/
      volumes:
        - ./composer2:/app
```

this docker-compose work correctly, but I don't understand why composer down quickly after 'docker-compose up -d'

PS:My first goal is to use this stack for symfony2 or silex

Answer (score 0):

The composer container is ended imediatelly becuase it's not intended to run as a "daemon". In case you don't provide any command, the composer, simply said, has nothing to do. Anyways, if it has "something to do", then it executes it and ends.

You can use it through interactive shell like this:

```
docker run --rm --interactive --tty --volume $PWD:/app composer install
```

More examples are in the "Using" section here: https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/